# Grid is not showing some values for columns from two tables

Tags: wpf, linq

Here I have a method to populate message fields

```
   public List<MessageFieldViewModel> GetAllViewModelMsgFields()
    {
        messageFieldVModel = messageField.GetAllMessageField().Select(msgFields => new MessageFieldViewModel
        {
            Id = msgFields.Id,
            Code = msgFields.Code,
            Name = msgFields.Name,
            Position = msgFields.Position,
            Length = msgFields.Length,
            IsMapped = (transactionRuleList.Any(tr => tr.SourceElementId == msgFields.Id)),
            MappingRule = transactionRuleList.Any(mapRule => mapRule.SourceElementId 
                                                             == msgFields.Id)?

                          transactionRuleList.First(mapRule => mapRule.SourceElementId 
                                                               == msgFields.Id).MappingRule

                          : null
        })
    .ToList();
        return messageFieldVModel;
    }
```

On my grid I want to show all values:

```
  <DataGrid   ItemsSource="{Binding MessageFields}" Margin="4,0,380,6" Grid.Row="2"    AutoGenerateColumns="False"  IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Id}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Binding="{Binding Code}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Field Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Position" Binding="{Binding Position}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Length" Binding="{Binding Length}" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="IsMapped">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsMapped}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="MappingRule" Binding="{Binding MappingRule}" /> 
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

// some  MessageField data

```
        MessageField.Add(new MessageFieldModel(01, "GMSLEN", "MESSAGE LENGTH", 5, 4));
        MessageField.Add(new MessageFieldModel(01, "GMSDST", "MESSAGE DESTINATION", 9, 7));
        MessageField.Add(new MessageFieldModel(011, "GMSOR", "MESSAGE ORIGIN", 16, 7));

        MessageField.Add(new MessageFieldModel(02, "GMSLEN", "MESSAGE LENGTH", 5, 4));
        MessageField.Add(new MessageFieldModel(02, "GMSDST", "MESSAGE DESTINATION", 9, 7));
        MessageField.Add(new MessageFieldModel(012, "GMSOR", "MESSAGE ORIGIN", 16, 7));
```

// some translation rule data

```
        TranslationRule.Add(new TranslationRuleModel(01, 01, 690, "direct"));
        TranslationRule.Add(new TranslationRuleModel(01, 01, 690, null));

        TranslationRule.Add(new TranslationRuleModel(02, 02, 690, "direct"));
        TranslationRule.Add(new TranslationRuleModel(02, 02, 690, null));

        TranslationRule.Add(new TranslationRuleModel(03, 03, 690, "direct"));
        TranslationRule.Add(new TranslationRuleModel(03, 03, 690, null));
```

now my grid is showing values for IsMapped  but for MappingRule I want to see both direct and null too. Currently it doesn't display null. Can someone help me understand what I do wrong?

Comment: For MappingRule, if your first `.Any()` call returns null, your ternary operator says to return null, so there's a potential that nothing would show.  IsMapped is harder to tell without some sample data from GetAllMessageField()

Comment: @GarrisonNeely I will update my post with some data.

Comment: It won't display "null", it will display nothing.  If you want it to display the word "null" there, you need to specifically replace it.  ASP.NET will display null as an empty string.

Comment: @GarrisonNeely do you mean specifically passing a "null" when I am creating the objects? something like TranslationRule.Add(new TranslationRuleModel(03, 03, 690, "NULL")) ?

Comment: There is a difference between "null" and `null` in C#.  The first is just a string, the second is the actual value of `null`.  If you pass a string "null", ASP.NET will display "null" on the page.  If you pass `null` to ASP.NET, nothing will display.

Comment: @GarrisonNeely I don't know if it is different for WPF and ASP.NET but my window wont will show "null" even if i pass "null"  string

Comment: Try a non-reserved word like "test123" instead of "null".

Comment: Oh, wait, did you change the `null` in this line to "null"?   MappingRule = transactionRuleList.Any(mapRule => mapRule.SourceElementId == msgFields.Id)?transactionRuleList.First(mapRule => mapRule.SourceElementId == msgFields.Id).MappingRule:null

Comment: Yes that is what I wanted to display on my grid for elements with isMapped value false.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out what was wrong with the query 
Here is what I was suppose to do

```
    MappingRule = transactionRuleList.Any(mapRule => mapRule.SourceElementId == msgFields.Id)
                          ?transactionRuleList.First(mapRule => mapRule.SourceElementId == msgFields.Id).MappingRule:"NULL"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I think I understand.  What does the MappingRule class declaration look like?  If you want to display the "direct" or "null" in MappingRule, your binding will have to be hooked to the property where it is stored.

For example, if "direct" is stored in MappingRule's Type property, your binding would have to be on MappingRule.Type, not MappingRule.

Maybe that helps?

Comment: Thank you.I think I found out what the problem is. I posted my answer below .